# How to play an original dvd (.vob file) in VLC?

Tags: video, dvd, vlc-media-player

When I play an original DVD in VLC, it does not play properly. i.e. it sticks too much, while on the other hand it plays smoothly in Windows Media Player (though it doesn't allow seeking).

The video files in the dvd are in .vob format. The other movies and clip in my pc that are also in .vob format are played perfectly by VLC. Why isn't it the case for this this DVD? Moreover I copied the entire DVD on my computer but the problem persists.

I'm using VLC 2.1.3 (Rincewind). How can I make it work well on VLC? Do I have to use another video player?

Answer (score 2):

If you copied all files to disk then just right click on that folder and choose 'play in VLC player. It will play the whole movie, starting with the [usually annoying] DVD menu.